# Google SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, encryption, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

When we open the site https://platform.mobivisits.com
sometimes it shows the SSL security error, that the connection is not private and may be unsafe to browse.

Although all the certificates are properly installed and site too opens most of the times.

So, sometimes it do not open and shows that error and its been quite hard to figure out why.

plz refer to the attached Screenshot of the error.

[SSL Certificate Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG4ii.jpg)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site to post bug reports for Google. Do you have a programming related question?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is not able to  recognize the identity of  website which you have opened (the reason may be that, the certificate is self signed or not configured properly). you can continue the application running through go in advance link of your error message and continue in unsafe mode.

note that, this error don't have any relevance with Google, it is expected

Answer (score 0):

You are not serving the full certificate chain (see [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=platform.mobivisits.com)). While most browsers will fetch it due to a feature called AIA chasing, [Chrome on Android doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284588/error-when-connecting-to-url-pkix-path-building-failed/33289012#33289012) and you see the error you've attached. Fix the chain and you should be good. You can use a tool like [What's My Chain Cert?](https://whatsmychaincert.com/?platform.mobivisits.com%20for) to generate this correct chain.

[image: SSL Labs report]